# Cross-thread conflicts in StructureMap

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, structuremap

I've got an API application that uses multiple database shards, with StructureMap for dependency injection.  One of the required headers in each API call is a `ShardKey`, which tells me which database this call is addressing.  To effect this, I have an `OwinMiddleware` class called `ShardingMiddleware`, which contains the following code (snipped for clarity):

```
var nestedContainer = container.GetNestedContainer();
using (var db = MyDbContext.ForShard(shardKey)) // creates a new MyDbContext with connection string appropriate to shardKey
{
    nestedContainer.Configure(cfg => cfg.For<MyDbContext>().Use(db));
    await Next.Invoke(context);
}
```

This works beautifully in my test environment and passes a battery of integration tests.

But the integration tests are effectively single-threaded.  When I deployed this into a QA environment, where a real app is hitting away at my API with multiple simultaneous calls, things start to go pear-shaped.  Ferinstance:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur is you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.

Or other exceptions indicating that StructureMap does not have a valid instance of `MyDbContext` available.

To me it seems that the multiple threads are somehow messing up each other's configuration, but for the life of me I can't understand how, seeing as I'm using a nested container to store the database context for each API call.

Any ideas what might be going wrong here?

**Update:** I also tried abstracting my Db context into an interface.  Made no real difference; I'm still getting the error

> System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'SomeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor. ---> StructureMap.StructureMapConfigurationException: No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type 'MyNamespace.IMyDbContext'

**Update 2:** I solved the problem, but the bounty is still open.  Please see my answer below.

Comment: Your `DbContext` might be kept alive as a [Captive Dependency](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/). Make sure that consumers of this dependency don't have a lifetime longer than that of the `DbContext` or -even better- prevent injecting the DbContext into consumers directly. A `DbContext` is runtime data, and runtime data [should not be injected into components](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99). Instead hide the DbContext behind an abstraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... I solved the problem, but I don't understand *why* this made a difference.

It boils down to some subtle differences from what I originally posted, which I left out because I thought the details were inconsequential and would have distracted from the question.  My container was not, in fact, defined locally; rather it was a protected property of my middleware (it's inherited for integration testing purposes):

```
protected IContainer Container { get; private set; }
```

Then there was an initialization call inside the `Invoke()` method:

```
Container = context.GetNestedContainer(); // gets the nested container created by a previous middleware class, using the context.Environment dictionary
```

Using logging statements throughout the method, I got down to the following code (as mentioned in the question, with logging added):

```
_logger.Debug($"Line 1 Context={context.GetHashCode}, Container={Container.GetHashCode()}");
var db = MyDbContext.ForShard(shardKey.Value);  // no need for "using", since DI will automatically dispose
_logger.Debug($"Line 2 Context={context.GetHashCode}, Container={Container.GetHashCode()}");
Container.Configure(cfg => cfg.For<MyDbContext>().Use(db));
await Next.Invoke(context);
```

And astoundingly, here's what came out of the logs:

> Line 1 Context=56852305, Container=48376271
>
> Line 1 Context=88275661, Container=85736099
>
> Line 2 Context=56852305, Container=85736099
>
> Line 2 Context=88275661, Container=85736099

Amazing!  The `Container` property of my middleware got magically replaced!  This, despite the fact that it is defined with a `private set`, and anyway, just to be safe, I checked through the code for `MyDbContext.ForShard()` and found nothing that could have messed up the reference for `Container`.

So what was the solution?  I declared a local `container` variable just after the initialization, and used that instead.

It works now, but I don't understand why or how this could have made a difference.

Bounty goes to the person who can explain this.

Comment: I think, reasons are same as described in 'Why Nested Containers over HttpContext or ThreadLocal Scoping?'  here http://structuremap.github.io/the-container/nested-containers/

Comment: @ATechieThought can you explain that more?  I was always using the OwinContext to get the container, not HttpContext or ThreadLocal scoping.

Comment: my bad. I missed it. but my thinking was somehow httpcontext was involved by looking at the context values. Now, httpcontext is out of the picture, is there any chance that MyDbContext is involved and it should be setup as singleton? Sorry, If, I am not helping any way towards reasoning of the problem.

Comment: @ATechieThought MyDbContext should definitely *not* be set up as a singleton.  That would make all threads use the same DB connection...  Unless I misunderstood you?

Answer (score 2):

You should rewrite this:

```
using (var db = MyDbContext.ForShard(shardKey)) // creates a new MyDbContext with connection string appropriate to shardKey
{
    nestedContainer.Configure(cfg => cfg.For<MyDbContext>().Use(db));
    await Next.Invoke(context);
}
```

cause `using` dispose your dbcontext at the end of using.

You should register factory instead:

```
var dbFactory = ()=>MyDbContext.ForShard(shardKey);
nestedContainer.Configure(cfg => cfg.For<Func<MyDbContext>>().Use(dbFactory));
await Next.Invoke(context);
```

and inject this Func instead of dbcontext instance.

Comment: If you inject a Func instead of an instance, will it open a new Db connection in every class where MyDbContext is injected?

Comment: it depends. by default - yes. Is it a problem?

Comment: Not sure if it is a problem.  My current way of thinking is that a single db connection should suffice for one unit of work.  I'm not sure if it might cause conflicts if there are more connections - or if it might put undue strain on the db to have too many connections opened... but that's for me to worry about.  Basically, if I want one connection per UOW, I'll pass the instance, and if I want one connection per repository, I'll use the Func.  Thanks!

Comment: If you want you can use single db context for whole shard. to do this you should register it as singleton in nested container and dispose on dispose of nested container. And not use using of dbcontext at all. There is a good book about dependency injection: Dependency Injection in .Net https://www.manning.com/books/dependency-injection-in-dot-net

Comment: Definitely not one db connection for the whole shard.  There will be multiple users; if two of them query the same shard at the same time, things will get ugly.

Comment: Your answer doesn't really solve the conundrum, but it's the best of all other answers, so I'll give you the bounty.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

From the logs what I see is that the second request/thread overrides the container and respectfully the database context of the first one so both use the same connection:

```
Line 2 Context=56852305, Container=85736099
```

should be

```
Line 2 Context=56852305, Container=48376271
```

or am I getting it wrong, so I don't think you solve it. The `System.ObjectDisposedException` 
error is from the
`using` 
clause that you use to create instance of your db context and because of it the `Next` 
delegate and the 
`context`
 are disposed. I also didn't understood the line

```
Container = context.GetNestedContainer();
```

maybe you had in mind

```
Container = container.GetNestedContainer();
```

? I am not familiar with StructureMap but I think the code should looks like this

```
var nestedContainer = Container.GetNestedContainer(c =>
                    {
                        var db = MyDbContext.ForShard(shardKey);
                        c.For<MyDbContext>().Use(db);
                    });

await Next.Invoke(context);
```

assuming that the container closes and disposes the db connection when it is disposed.